# Do URL parameters make duplicate pages for search engines?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, duplicate-content, url-parameters

I found in HTML Improvements section google search console about 1200 duplicate meta title, then I checked one of them for example Tehran to Qeshm flights:

- `/flights/THR-GSM/1392-02-02/1-0-0`
- `/flights/THR-GSM/1392-08-10/1-0-0`
- `/flights/THR-GSM/1395-06-17/1-0-0`
- `/flights/THR-GSM?adult=1&child=0&infant=0&departing=1397-02-20&step=results`
- `/flights/THR-GSM?departing=1393-10-12&adult=1&child=0&infant=0`
- `/flights/THR-GSM?departing=1393-10-15&adult=1&child=0&infant=0`

In fact, the main URL for the page is: `/flights/THR-GSM`, but when users search in search box for a specific date, child and adult or other parameters, they would include in URLs as you see above.  It appears that Google sees them as different pages and lists them in "duplicate meta titles" section.

Why does this happen?  Why are they are shown as separate and different pages?

Should I use canonical tags for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It has shown as title and may also description duplicate, because you have used one title and description for it. in fact you did not have a parameter that shows Google and Google, pages serve different content.

Based on your business strategy you have two solutions:

if your pages have equal value, you can choose the most visited page and use cannibalization for it.

but if each page has its own value you should generate parameters and filters first of your of your title and description. it can index pages based on their value and lead users to best result